# Angular show No data found when ngIf failed inside a ngfor

Tags: javascript, angular

I have array , display it as a list and apply some conditions to filter it.I wanna show no data found when the condition failed.

.ts

```
  @Input() Minage;
  @Input() Gender;
   name = '';

 items = [
          {name:'name01' , age : 14, gender : 'male'},
          {name:'name02' , age : 25, gender : 'female'},
          {name:'name03' , age : 24, gender : 'male'},
          {name:'name04' , age : 16, gender : 'female'},
          {name:'name05' , age : 24, gender : 'male'},
      ]
```

.html

```
     <p>
     <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" (ngModelChange)="name"/>
    </p>

    <p *ngFor="let item of items">
       <ng-container  *ngIf='item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) !== -1 && 
             item.age > Minage && item.gender === Gender'>

               {{item.name}}

       </ng-container>

    </p>
```

Input Minage & Gender are dynamic values.

The above code works perfectly for search filter. But I could not show no data found.How to show no data found when the search condition failed in the array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than performing complex operations in your HTML, I would recommend performing them in the model. Filter the items in the model, and bind to the results in the HTML.

You will then need to filter the items whenever the `@Input()` properties change in `ngOnChanges()` or whenever the `name` input changes.

```js
@Input() Minage;
@Input() Gender;

name = '';
items = [
  {name:'name01' , age : 14, gender : 'male'},
  {name:'name02' , age : 25, gender : 'female'},
  {name:'name03' , age : 24, gender : 'male'},
  {name:'name04' , age : 16, gender : 'female'},
  {name:'name05' , age : 24, gender : 'male'},
];
results = this.items.slice();

ngOnChanges(): void {
  this.filterItems();
}

onNameChange(): void {
  this.filterItems();
}

filterItems(): void {
  this.results = this.items.filter(item => {
    return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.name.toLowerCase()) !== -1 
      && item.age > this.Minage && item.gender === this.Gender;
  });
}
```

And then your HTML becomes simple:

```html
<p>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" (ngModelChange)="onNameChange()" />
</p>

<p *ngFor="let item of results">
  {{item.name}}
</p>
<p *ngIf="results.length === 0>
  No results found
</p>
```